# Upgrade Elasticsearch from 1.6.0 to Newer Versions

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-boot

Context:

While trying to upgrade Spring Boot to 1.4.x (or newer), we wanted to upgrade Elasticsearch from 1.6.x to 2.4.x and faced the following problem:

1. The application failed to start with error: `script.disable_dynamic is not a supported setting, replace with fine-grained script settings.`
2. Test cases fail due to error: `script file extension not supported [groovy]`
3. Test cases fail due to error while parsing queries: `must specify a script in script fields`.

How to solve these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions for the above problems while upgrading to newer version of Elsaticsearch:

1. We had `script.disable_dynamic = false` in the configuration. In the new version of Elasticsearch, the setting is removed and replaced with fine-grained script settings as clearly stated in the error message. We replaced it with the following (you should look at the documentation for the best configuration):

   ```
   script.file = true // we needed this for our script files
   script.inline = false
   script.indexed = false
   ```
2. For testing we use Elasticsearch Cluster Runner with a couple of Groovy scripts. For the new version of Elasticsearch you need to explicitly add the required dependency to the project:

   ```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.elasticsearch.module</groupId>
     <artifactId>lang-groovy</artifactId>
     <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. You may have to update/change your queries to resolve issue #3. For example we had the following:

   ```
   {
     ...
     "script_fields" : {
       "channel" : { "file": "channel_calc" },
       "data" : { "file": "data_search_calc_v3" }
     },
     "_source": "*"
     ...
   }
   ```

   And we had to wrap `file` nodes in a `script` node:

   ```
   {
     ...
     "script_fields" : {
       "channel" : { "script" : { "file": "channel_calc" } },
       "data" : { "script" : { "file": "data_search_calc_v3" } }
     },
     "_source": "*"
     ...
   }
   ```

Hope it helps others.
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend running your cluster with the [elasticsearch migration plugin](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-migration), it gives you a good overview of what would break and the things that you might want to change in terms of configuration of your cluster, when you want to upgrade. These may be the problems that you've encountered now, but the plugin would give you the issues that you could face in the future as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Correct me if I'm wrong: this plugin could/should be used while migrating the cluster not the client. (I had the problems while upgrading the client.)